# Simple WYSIWYG editor : remove formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor

Recently I study a tutorial to build a simple WYSIWYG editor **without using design mode / execCommand**.

Finally I have come up with the solution like this:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="addClassToSelection('underline')"><b>U</b></button>
<button onclick="addClassToSelection('bold')"><b>B</b></button>

<select id="color_select">
    <option value="">Change Color</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>

<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable>Test test test</div>
```

JS:

```
   function addClassToSelection(class_name){
            var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange();
            if(sel.getRangeAt){
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                var newNode = document.createElement("span"); 
                newNode.setAttribute('class', class_name);
                range.surroundContents(newNode);
            } else {
                //sel.pasteHTML('<span class="someclass">'+sel.htmlText+'</span>');
            }
        }

color_select.onchange = function(){
        //alert(color_select.value);
        addClassToSelection(color_select.value);
    };
```

It has create a styled span surrounding the selected string. The problem is , how to remove the style, especially when the style is overlap?

Thanks a lot

**Update:**
Thanks for upvoting , just think of a temp solution:

if there are two bold , then the style return to normal, like this:

```
.bold .bold {
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

however, this apply for one time only, can check for the even / odd case in css? thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?